# django orm select from case when

Tags: django, orm, case-when

I wanna to fetch some data from a subquery through Django ORM. 
here is my excepted SQL

```
SELECT "risk_level", COUNT("t"."id") 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        "task_taskreport"."id" as "id",
    CASE
       WHEN MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") >= 8.0 THEN 'high'
       WHEN (MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") >= 5.0 AND MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") <= 7.0) THEN 'middle'
       WHEN (MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") >= 2.0 AND MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") <= 4.0) THEN 'low'
       WHEN MAX("task_vuln"."severity_points") <= 1.0 THEN 'none'
      ELSE NULL
   END AS "risk_level"
   FROM "task_taskreport"
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "task_taskreport_vuln" ON ("task_taskreport"."id" = 
   "task_taskreport_vuln"."task_report_id")
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "task_vuln" ON ("task_taskreport_vuln"."vuln_id" = "task_vuln"."vul_id")
   WHERE "task_taskreport"."subtask_id" = 21
   GROUP BY "task_taskreport"."id" ORDER BY "task_taskreport"."id" DESC) as t 
   group by "risk_level";
```

i have tried this

```
TaskReport.objects.filter(subtask__pk=self.pk).\
            annotate(max_points=Max('vulns__severity_points')).annotate(
            risk_level=Case(
                When(max_points__gte=8, then=Value('high')),
                When(max_points__gte=5, max_points__lte=7, then=Value('middle')),
                When(max_points__gte=2, max_points__lte=4, then=Value('low')),
                When(max_points__lte=1, then=Value('none')),
                output_field=models.CharField(),
            )
        ).values('risk_level', 'pk').annotate(count=Count('risk_level'))
```

but this throws an exception

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Count('risk_level'): 'risk_level' is an aggregate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complicated SQL query that does exactly what you want, you can [perform a raw SQL query in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/) and use it as a QuerySet.

Here's the example from that page of the Django docs:

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones
```